# 「Upcoming changes on Inactive models on AutoML Natural Language Content Classification from January 22」とは？

Tags: google-cloud

お世話になります。

私は、Google Cloud AutoML Natural Language を利用しています。
２つのプロジェクトを作成して、データセットを準備し、モデルのトレーニングを行ってきています。
利用例としては、機械学習モデルを、AutoML Natural Language UIからデータセットのアップロード、トレーニングを行い、
仮想マシンを立ち上げて、REST APIまたはPython（同UIで表示された下図のソースコードを配置して）で、

[image: 使用したソースコード]

当該モデルを呼び出して結果を取得する、といった流れを試してみているところです。

そこで、最近、以下のようなメールが、サポートから送られてきました。

> Hello Google Cloud AutoML NL Content Classification Customer,
>
> We are writing to let you know that from January 22, 2019, trained
> Cloud AutoML Natural Language (NL) models that have no prediction
> traffic for 7 or more weeks will be silently undeployed and archived.
>
> What do I need to do? Starting January 22, 2019, we will start
> undeploying all inactive Cloud AutoML NL models. If you'd like to
> continue using these models, you will need to re-deploy your Cloud
> AutoML NL models with the Deploy API that will be made available on
> January 22, 2019. The Deploy API can be used from January 22, 2019
> onwards to redeploy models that receive an "undeployed model" error.
> Your AutoML NL prediction API will function seamlessly against these
> trained models once the Deploy API is run.
>
> Your projects listed below currently use AutoML NL Content
> Classification and may be affected by this change:
>
> ・ni*****（自分のプロジェクトID 1つ目）
> ・ja*****（自分のプロジェクトID 2つ目）
>
> Need more information or help? If you have any questions or require assistance, please reply to this email to contact Google Cloud Support.

文面を読む限り、
`re-deploy your Cloud AutoML NL models with the Deploy API`
をしなくてはならないようですが、
**どのような手順でこれを行えばよろしいでしょうか**。

はたまた、本来、AutoML Natural Languageを仮想マシンでなく本番環境で使用する場合は、
**モデルのトレーニングの次に行う手順はあるのでしょうか**。

勉強不足で申し訳ございません。お力をお貸しくだされば幸いです。